# Как запушить в общий репозиторий GitHub только те файлы которые я добавил или изменил?

Tags: git, github

Есть общий проект, над ним работает несколько человек. Например туда кто-то внес изменения которых у меня на локальном репозитории нет. И вот я тоже хочу добавить какие-то файлы. Как мне запушить так, чтобы изменения того кто туда запушил до меня не потерялись, а я в свою очередь отправил туда не все файлы, а только те которые я изменил/добавил? Знаю что для начала надо сделать git pull , а вот потом как правильно добавить файлы в коммит, чтобы после моего коммита не потерялись файлы других учасников(которых у меня нет на локалке) на удаленном репозиторие? Спасибо.

Comment: Нашел для вас толковое объяснение в скринкасте по git, думаю вы так надолго закроете этот вопрос. Приятного просмотра. Надеюсь я вам помог. [Ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOvHGNtjCwE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы сделали клон, а уже были внесены изменения, и вы сделали git pull.

Git сам найдет изменения, что таких-то файлов нету, и добавит их.

Дабы избежать конфликтов вы должны сделать git pull, а после выполнить этот код:

```
git add (название файлов через пробел)
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

Comment: Спасибо, и еще вопрос, а если файлов много, мне их все через пробел перечислять?

Comment: @unsxxn `git add ./*`

Comment: Лучше используйте: git add --all

Comment: `git add .` - если уж все. Через пробел если, то сколько угодно, но смысл? Если есть ограничения какие-то, то пропишите их в `.gitignore`. Странно что вы вообще все одну ветку коммитите